# Compare dates in the format 1 year 2 months 3 weeks 4 days in PHP

Tags: php

In the project I am working, I get an age like

```
1Year 2Months 3Weeks 4Days
```

I am trying to do a comparison like

> If age is less than 8 weeks, then it is a `baby`
>   If age less than or equal to 12 months/1 year then it is `young`
>   If greater than 1 year, it is `adult`. The code which I try is given below. It is confusing.

**Is there a way to simplify this using some in built functions?**

```
function getAgeGroup($age_years, $age_months, $age_weeks, $age_days) {
$age_group = 'baby';
if (!$age_years && !$age_months && (!$age_weeks || ($age_weeks <= 8 && (!$age_days || $age_days < 1)))) {
  $age_group = 'baby';
}
elseif (!$age_years && ($age_months == 1 || $age_months == 2) && (!$age_weeks && !$age_days)) {
  $age_group = 'baby';
}
elseif (!$age_years && $age_months == 1 && $age_weeks < 4 && $age_days) {
  $age_group = 'young';
}
elseif (!$age_years && $age_months == 1 && $age_weeks > 4) {
  $age_group = 'young';
}
elseif (!$age_years && ($age_months >= 2 && $age_months < 12) && ($age_weeks > 0 || $age_days > 0)) {
  $age_group = 'young';
}
elseif (!$age_years && ($age_months > 0 && $age_months <= 12) && ($age_weeks >= 8 && $age_days > 1)) {
  $age_group = 'young';
}
elseif (!$age_years && ($age_months > 2 && $age_months <= 12) && (!$age_weeks && !$age_days)) {
  $age_group = 'young';
}
elseif ($age_years == 1 && !$age_months && !$age_weeks && !$age_days) {
  $age_group = 'young';
}
elseif (($age_years > 0 || $age_months >= 12) && ($age_weeks > 0 || $age_days > 0)) {
  $age_group = 'adult';
}
elseif (($age_years > 0 || $age_months > 0)) {
  $age_group = 'adult';
}
elseif ($age_years > 1) {
  $age_group = 'adult';
}
return $age_group;
}
```

Comment: a `switch` statement would clean this up - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 0):

you can try to something like this: [eval.in](https://eval.in/799986) to get use of the `DateTime` and `DateInterval` classes.